# Command text was not set for the command object using vb and ms-access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

The question:
-Display a message for validation if the user entered existing data (name, staff id, phone number, username and password).

THESE ARE THE CODES

my database works but the msgbox appeared saying the command text wat not set for the command object

```
pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\SEM 5\CSC301\ASSESSMENT 3\database.accdb"
    connstring = pro
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
    myconnection.Open()


    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\SEM 5\CSC301\ASSESSMENT 3\database.accdb"
    con.Open()

    Dim registercmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from users where [Librarian Name]='" & txtName.Text & "' or [Staff ID]='" &
                                                       txtStaffID.Text & "' or [Phone Number]='" & txtPhone.Text & "' or [Username]='" &
                                                       txtUsername.Text & "' or [Password]='" & txtPassword.Text & "'", con)
    Dim registerrd As OleDbDataReader = registercmd.ExecuteReader
    If (registerrd.Read() = True) Then
        Me.Hide()
        MessageBox.Show("Account Exist!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Me.Hide()
        Me.Show()
        txtName.Clear()
        txtStaffID.Clear()
        txtPhone.Clear()
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtPassword.Clear()
    Else
        command = "insert into users([Librarian Name],[Staff ID],[Phone Number],[Username],[Password]) 
               Values('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtStaffID.Text & "','" & txtPhone.Text & "','" & txtUsername.Text & "','" & txtPassword.Text & "')"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ID", CType(txtName.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Librarian Name", CType(txtStaffID.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Staff ID", CType(txtPhone.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Phone Number", CType(txtUsername.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Username", CType(txtPassword.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Password", CType(txtPassword.Text, String)))
        MsgBox("Account Created")

        Me.Hide()
        Login.ShowDialog()
    End If

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myconnection.Close()
        txtName.Clear()
        txtStaffID.Clear()
        txtPhone.Clear()
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtPassword.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Although there are a number off issues with your code and could really do with a fairly hefty tidy up, not sure exactly why either,  have you debugged/stepped through your program to ensure that the cmd object is as expected when you try to execute the query?

Comment: `If (registerrd.Read() = True)`? Do you mean `If registerrd.HasRows Then ...`. -- Build that query using Parameters, too. -- This is useless: `CType(txtStaffID.Text, String`, `Text` is already a string. Are `[ID]` `[Staff ID]` strings or a numeric value? -- In the second command, the parameter you add don't match the query's. Check out what `ID` is set to. Also, you're concatenating strings instead of using the parameters.

Comment: This is all quite a mess. You can find a gazillion posts in SO related to querying a database.

Answer (score 0):

Your code starts out with several undeclared variables. The connection string variable can be a class level variable so it can be used in several methods. Then you open a connection that you don't use until half way down the code. Don't open connections utill directly before the `.Execute...`. I read a very good analogy here on Stack Overflow. Connections are like refrigerator doors. Open only when you must. Get out or put in what you need to as quickly as possible. Then close as soon as possible. You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection.

Database objects need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us even if there is an error. I had to guess at the data type of the parameters. Please check your database for the correct type and correct the code accordingly.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\SEM 5\CSC301\ASSESSMENT 3\database.accdb"

Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            registercmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from users where 
                                                            [Librarian Name]= @Name or 
                                                            [Staff ID]= @StaffID or 
                                                            [Phone Number]= @Phone or 
                                                            [Username]= @User or 
                                                            [Password]= @PWord;", con)
        With registercmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtName.Text
            .Add("@StaffID", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtStaffID.Text 'Often an ID is a numeric type. Check your database.
            .Add("@Phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPhone.Text
            .Add("@User", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
            .Add("@PWord", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
        End With
        con.Open()
        Using registered = registercmd.ExecuteReader
            If registered.HasRows Then
                exists = True
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    If exists Then
        MessageBox.Show("Account Exist!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("insert into users([Librarian Name],[Staff ID],[Phone Number],[Username],[Password]) 
           Values(@Name, @StaffID, @Phone, @UserName, @PWord);", con)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtName.Text
                .Add("@StaffID", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtStaffID.Text
                .Add("@Phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPhone.Text
                .Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
                .Add("@PWord", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
            End With
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        MsgBox("Account Created")
        Hide()
        Login.ShowDialog()
    End If
    txtName.Clear()
    txtStaffID.Clear()
    txtPhone.Clear()
    txtUsername.Clear()
    txtPassword.Clear()
End Sub
```

Another bad problem that I see. Your appear to be storing passwords as plain text. All passwords should be salted and encrypted.